# Multiple Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

The first three characters must be capital letters excluding I, O, S or Z. Then a dash then four characters that can be anything other than 3. I have this but the first negative lookahead is capturing also things outside of the first capturing group.

```
^((?!.*[IOSZ])[A-Z]{3})-((?!.*3)(.{4}))$
```

I would like to capture `AAA-444Z` for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `.*` from your look ahead, because you want to match 3 character and put the limit number out of capture group. Also use a negated character class for last part:

```
^((?![IOSZ])[A-Z]){3}-[^3]{4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO4yC2/1)

If you want to use two negative look ahead use following:

```
^((?![IOSZ])[A-Z]){3}-((?!3).){4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO4yC2/2)

Note that the point is that when you use look-around you want to specify that a pattern is follows or precedes by a special pattern and when you want to lint the number of character you need to say the regex engine to consider the limitation for whole of your look-around based pattern. In first one `(?![IOSZ])[A-Z])` and in second one `((?!3).)`.

Comment: thanks i would like to do this with two negative lookaheads to understand the mechanism

Comment: `^((?![IOSZ])([A-Z]{3}))-((?!3)(.{4}))$` would do it too

Comment: I chose your answer because it's simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any lookahead for this requirement as you can use this regex:

```
^[A-HJ-NP-RT-Y]{3}-[^3]{4}$
```

- `[A-HJ-NP-RT-Y]{3}` will match 3 instances of upper case letters that are not `I, O, S or Z`.
- `[^3]{4}` matches any character that is not `3`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD9kX1/1)

As per comment below if you really want to negative lookaheads only then use:

```
^(?:(?![IOSZ])[A-Z]){3}-(?:(?!3).){4}$
```

[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/aD9kX1/3)

Comment: thanks. i want to do it with negative lookahead to understand this in general not to answer a question.

Comment: great thanks! I did not know of non capturing groups